# ASP.Net validation not fireing for hidden fileds

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-validators

I have 3 required fields on my page and 2 of them are hidden. The hidden fields values are filled by jQuery based off the selection of dropdown lists. If I just leave everything blank so that none of the fields are every filled in and hit the submit button the `@Html.ValidationSummery()` only lists an error for the 1 visible field. How can I get it to show errors when the hidden fields don't have a value as well?

The code for my hidden fields:

```
<li>
    <label for="SelectedProjects">Selected Projects:</label>
    <select size="1" id="SelectedProjects" name="SelectedProjects" multiple="multiple"></select> <button class="removeButton" data-codetype="Project" type="button">-</button>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedProjectCodes)
</li>

<li>
    <label for="SelectedTasks">Selected Tasks:</label>
    <select size="1" multiple="multiple" id="SelectedTasks" name="SelectedTasks"></select> <button class="removeButton" data-codetype="Task" type="button">-</button>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedTaskCodes)
</li>
```

The HTML rendered:

```
        <li>
            <label for="SelectedProjects">Selected Projects:</label>
            <select size="1" id="SelectedProjects" name="SelectedProjects" multiple="multiple"></select> <button class="removeButton" data-codetype="Project" type="button">-</button>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedProjectCodes field is required." id="SelectedProjectCodes" name="SelectedProjectCodes" type="hidden" value="" />
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="SelectedTasks">Selected Tasks:</label>
            <select size="1" multiple="multiple" id="SelectedTasks" name="SelectedTasks"></select> <button class="removeButton" data-codetype="Task" type="button">-</button>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedTaskCodes field is required." id="SelectedTaskCodes" name="SelectedTaskCodes" type="hidden" value="" />
        </li>
```

The properties in the ViewModel backing it:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false), Required]
public string SelectedProjectCodes { get; set; }

[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false), Required]
public string SelectedTaskCodes { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is by design. There's no point in notifying a user about an error in a field they cannot edit. If you want the field validated, then it should be a normal text box or such which a user could control. Otherwise, it's up to your application to ensure it has a value, without involving the user.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I disagree, the filed is used to track multiple options the users selects so there is a point in notifying the user of an error when the hidden field is blank as that indicates they did not make one or more selections. I also figured it was by design but most behavior has a way to override the default design and knowing how to do that will be helpful to me and probably others.

Comment: No. If the user failed to make other selections, then the error should be on *those other selections*, not the hidden field.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Except the field the user inputs to is not persistent. As soon as they select a project is locks up then they select a task and it clears allowing them to select another task so running the validation on that field would make them always fail.

Comment: That's a UI concern, and should be treated as such. The simple fact remains that the validation error needs to go where the user actually has power to do something about it. The whole point of hidden field is that it's not supposed to be modified by a user, so presenting a validation error there serves no purpose. How is the user supposed to resolve that?

Comment: By following the directions of the error message and selecting a project/task. I just noticed that the code I posted did not have custom error message in it. It will read "Please select at least one project" or "Please select a task for each project"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default jQuery validation (which is what MVC uses) ignores hidden fields.  You can adjust this by changing the default setting when the page loads.  One way might be to add an class to the hidden fields to force them to be validated.

```
<li>
    <label for="SelectedProjects">Selected Projects:</label>
    <select size="1" id="SelectedProjects" name="SelectedProjects" multiple="multiple"></select> <button class="removeButton" data-codetype="Project" type="button">-</button>
    <input class="force-validation" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedProjectCodes field is required." id="SelectedProjectCodes" name="SelectedProjectCodes" type="hidden" value=""/>
</li>
```

the the javacript to change the defaults would look like this

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ":hidden:not(.force-validation)"
});
```